# unable to enter the value second time in same text field in C# selenium

Tags: selenium, c#

I entered one value in text field, using this code

```
driver.findelement(By.Id("Text"+Keys.enter));
```

Then, I used same id to enter second value in same text field

```
driver.findelement(By.id("Text2"+Keys.enter));
```

I think this is not the correct way to enter second value. Can I get an alternate way to do this? please!

Comment: Is it actually inserting Text into a textbox on this first one? I don't see how, personally.

Comment: does your code even compile? could you please give more context code for this issue?

Comment: yes, its taking first value

Comment: how i can enter second value in same field with same id?

Comment: May be you can enter both text once itself. Don't you? Suggestion - You need to add details for your question if you are really need help. Due to lack of info closing this question

Answer (score 1):

So, time for some Selenium basics. I will try and be thorough so others can use this as time goes by.

When learning Selenium and Development it is important to understand what a method is doing. It's important to understand what you're code is doing. Let's assume you have you're WebDriver up and running and that you are in a place to actually call methods on it.

**IWebDriver**

1. GoToUrl

   - This method navigates the browser to a URL. Pretty simple.

     ```
     IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
     driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
     ```
2. FindElement

   - This method finds a single element on the current page.
   - If there is more than one matching element it will return the first element.
   - Returns an instance of IWebElement.
   - If no elements are found, throws an exception

     ```
     IWebElement searchField = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
     ```
3. FindElements

   - Much like FindElement but returns multiple IWebElement
   - Returns as an `IList<IWebElement>`
   - Does not throw an exception if no matching Elements

     ```
     IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.Name("q"));
     ```

**By**

1. Allows a user to search for elements

   - `By.ClassName` finds the element by it's class
   - `By.CssSelector` uses a CSS selector to find it. I typically use this method when ID is not available
   - `By.LinkText` uses the text of a Link
   - `By.Name` uses the Name of the element
   - `By.PartialLinkText` uses a partial match of a link text
   - `By.TagName` uses a match based on the HTML tag
   - `By.XPath` uses an XPath matcher

**IWebElement**

1. SendKeys

   - Sends keys into the element.

     ```
     searchField.SendKeys("Selenium Tutorial");
     ```
2. Clear

   - Clears out the text in the field

     ```
     searchField.Clear();
     ```
3. Click

   - Clicks on the element

     ```
     searchField.Click();
     ```

And to compile together to do something:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
IWebElement searchField = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
searchField.SendKeys("Testing");
searchField.Clear();
searchField.SendKeys("Selenium Tutorial");
searchField.Submit();
```

Comment: this would be great for the documentation site, but I don't think this is going to help the OP, I think they need to give us a little more information, or as you put it, go back to the basics

Comment: @Malachi I agree with your assessment, especially about needing more information. Hopefully this will assist the OP in understanding the differences between FindElement and SendKeys (as I believe the OP is trying to SendKeys with FindElement function) and assist in the questions that they will be having very soon.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> driver.findelement(By.Id("Text"+Keys.enter));
> ```

This piece of code is finding the element on the page with an ID of `"text" + Keys.enter`  (whatever `Keys.enter` translates to in the compiler).

This line of code ***Does Not enter text into the text attribute of the element***.  [You need to first Find the element, then send the value to the element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559366/1214743), something like this

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ElementID"));
element.SendKeys("text" + Keys.enter);
```

Or you can do it all in one line without assigning the element to a variable.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ElementID")).SendKeys("text" + Keys.enter);
```

You can do it like this the first time.  If you want to replace what is in the textbox then you need to do something different.

When I want to replace the text I could figure out how to delete what I know is in there, but that could turn ugly, so instead I make use of the Driver's `ExecuteScript` method like this

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ElementID"));
var text = "text you want in your element's value attribute";
driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", element, text);
```

The `FindElement` method just returns an `IWebElement` based on the search parameters that you give it.

I don't think that you want to find the element with the ID of `"text" + Keys.enter`, `Keys.enter` returns a key code for the enter key, not a function or an action.

---

You are not grabbing the same element. you are giving each command a different ID so they are looking for two different elements.

the first line

> ```
> driver.findelement(By.Id("Text"+Keys.enter));
> ```

has a different ID than the second line

> ```
> driver.findelement(By.id("Text2"+Keys.enter));
> ```

so when you put these into a variable they are actually two different elements

```
var firstElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("id1"));
var secondElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("id2"));
var areElementsTheSame = firstElement == secondElement;
```

`areElementsTheSame` is false.

you haven't put anything into any text field on the page when you run either line of code that you have posted, that is a different operation.

Comment: as you told id's are not different they are same. I want to enter other value in the same field with same id. so how can i do this

Comment: The id's in your code are different.  you are passing different ID's from one line of code to the next.  they are ***NOT*** the same in your code you posted.  I have edited my answer to show you a way of doing what you are asking.

Comment: Answer you told after entering first value you are giving clear code and then you entering the new value in  the same field. Yes that is true, and its scenario we can do but, I want to enter the new value in same field without clearing the first value.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way, @santhoshnayak?

Comment: @santhoshnayak, I rolled back my most recent edit, because it actually overwrites the text in the element's text attribute.  but this isn't clicking in the box and backspacing (or deleting) the text that is attribute.  I am still unclear of the specifications, I think you should try to better explain your situation, in your post.